How to apply AnimatedVisibility and animateItemPlacement together?
I am using androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.06.00. The items of a LazyColumn are animated at the launch of the screen:
@Composable
fun SampleList(samples: List<Sample>) {
    val state = rememberLazyListState()
    LazyColumn(
        Modifier.padding(16.dp),
        state = state,
    ) {
        item {
            SampleHeader()
        }
        itemsIndexed(samples, key = { _, item -> item.name }) { index, item ->
            var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

            LaunchedEffect(key1 = index) {
                delay(index * 100L) // Staggered delay
                visible = true
            }

            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = visible,
                enter = slideInHorizontally(
                    initialOffsetX = { fullWidth -> if (index % 2 == 0) -fullWidth else fullWidth },
                    animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 300)
                ),
            ) {
                SampleItem(item, Modifier /* .animateItemPlacement() */)
            }
        }
    }
}

Problem 1
Since, the animation is added the items are no longer scrollable in landscape orientation. The list of items appears cut-off.
Problem 2
When I add Modifier.animateItemPlacement() to animate sorting order change of the items then this does not have any effect.
When I apply the same code without AnimatedVisibility it works perfect as in the following snippet.
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun SampleList(samples: List<Sample>) {
    LazyColumn(
        Modifier.padding(16.dp),
        state = rememberLazyListState(),
    ) {
        item {
            SampleHeader()
        }
        items(samples, key = { it.name }) {
            SampleItem(it, Modifier.animateItemPlacement())
        }
    }
}

Related

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-animation#3
https://github.com/android/codelab-android-compose/blob/main/AnimationCodelab/finished/src/main/java/com/example/android/codelab/animation/ui/home/Home.kt
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/animation-in-lazycolumn-and-lazyrow-in-android-jetpack-compose/
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150812265


Adding delay in item for animation will reduce performance. Currently there is no add item / list item show animation in compose listing. Will have to wait for a real solution from compose team
